# HTML Form POST to PHP page

Tags: php, html, forms

ok...i created a form.html page. It asks the user to input into 6 text fields.  The form POSTs to a separate page called myform.php.  The myform.php page simply just returns the values the user entered.  However, when I click submit I just get the myform.php source code popping up on the screen.

```
<div class="content">
        <form action="myform.php" method="post">
            Name: <input name="name" type="text" size="25" />
            Course: <input name="course" type="text" size="25" />
            Book: <input name="book" type="text" size="255" />
            Price: <input name="price" type="text" size="7" />
            Email: <input name="email" type="text" size="255" />
            Phone #: <input name="phone" type="text" size="12" />

            <input name="mySubmit" type="submit" value="submit" />
        </form>
    </div>

<?php
$name = $_POST["name"];
$course = $_POST["course"];
$book = $_POST["book"];
$price = $_POST["price"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$phone = $_POST["phone"];

?>
</head>

<body>
<?php
    echo $name;
    ?>
</body>
```

Comment: have you installed and enabled PHP into your web server?

Comment: Is this code in a place where PHP running?

Comment: nevermind...I had the page in the wrong direction for xampp :S

Comment: *directory not direction

Answer (score 8):

Marc Towler is correct.  You need to have the page with the extension of PHP for PHP code to be parsed in the first place.  But I'd actually suggest you separate the pages of your form and your form processing.  I'd suggest the following:

myform.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>   
<div class="content">
    <form action="formprocessor.php" method="POST">
        <label>Name: </label>
        <input name="name" type="text" size="25" />

        <label>Course: </label>
        <input name="course" type="text" size="25" />

        <label>Book: </label>
        <input name="book" type="text" size="255" />

        <label>Price: </label>
        <input name="price" type="text" size="7" />

        <label>Email: </label>
        <input name="email" type="text" size="255" />

        <label>Phone #: </label>
        <input name="phone" type="text" size="12" />

        <input name="mySubmit" type="submit" value="Submit!" />
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

formprocessor.php:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST["name"];
$course = $_POST["course"];
$book = $_POST["book"];
$price = $_POST["price"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$phone = $_POST["phone"];

echo $name;
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your big issue is in your first sentence

> ok...i created a form.html page

To run PHP code on your server you need to rename the file form.php unless you have combined both files in your code example....

Comment: You missed the point. His php form handler doesn't get executed. His form.html page is a separate file and is irrelevant.