# I am unable to retrieve data from a $_POST or $_GET on an HTML form with PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I've been all over stack overflow and other various google searches. I have not been able to figure out why this is happening.

I receive emails and any plaintext that is hard coded in the PHP file works fine. However, I am unable to use $_GET or $_POST to pull the data from the HTML form. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Form submission code:

```
<form  action="sendemail.php" method="post" id="main-contact-form" class="contact-form" name="contact-form" role="form">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Name">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="useremail" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Email address">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea type="text" name="usermessage" id="message" required="required" class="form-control" rows="8" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" value="Send message"></input>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

PHP page code:

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    $status = array(
        'type'=>'success',
        'message'=>'Email sent!'
    );

    $name = $_POST['username']; 
    $email = $_POST['useremail']; 
    $subject = 'Webform Submission.'; 
    $message = $_POST['usermessage']; 

    $email_from = $email;
    $email_to = 'test@test.com';

    $body = "Name: " . $name . "\n\n" . "Email: " . $email . "\n\n" . "Subject: " . $subject . "\n\n" . "Message: " . $message;

    $success = @mail($email_to, $subject, $body);

    echo json_encode($status);
    die; 

?>
```

This is the Data that gets sent in the e-mail:

```
Name: 

Email: 

Subject: Webform Submission.

Message:
```

Update: I've been messing around and I am still not able to get any data grabbed from the index.php file. This is what I used to test this theory:

```
<?php 
    $raw_post = file_get_contents('php://input');
    var_dump($raw_post);
?>
```

As well as:

```
<?php
    var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

I am starting to think it is a server setting, involving the php.ini or the .htaccess file. However, none of the suggestions I have found have worked. I am still at a loss for this issue.

Comment: All seems good can you write `<pre>
<?php var_dump($_POST); ?>
</pre>` in your PHP code!

Comment: Yes @Akshay is right. i am able to see `$_POST` variables.

Comment: You are getting username and all in PHP code right?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057752/html-form-post-to-php-page

Comment: did you ensure that sendmail.php file is called

Comment: So are you saying that if you do `$name = 'Bob'` the text shows up, but if you do `$name = $_POST['username']` then name does not show up?

Comment: @BizzyBob Yes. That is exactly what is happening.

Comment: @kannan If sendmail.php was not called, it wouldn't be sending mail.

Comment: @Akshay I apologize, I added what you asked me to in my code, and it stops the submission from working. Is there a specific area in the code I should be adding it to?

Comment: @channasmcs When I change index.html to index.php, I get the same result.

Comment: @ElizaDev befor ` $name = $_POST['username'];`;

Comment: @Akshay I have added it, however e-mail submission no longer occurs. I apologize if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: It won't send email it will print data whatever you are getting in post

Comment: @Akshay It is sending emails. I am not seeing the values for the var_dump. It is not redirecting to the PHP page.

Comment: @ElizaDev comment the mail code brother first check whether you are getting data in post or not in browser it self.

Comment: @Akshay I apologize, I do not understand what you are asking me to do. Specifically, what does "mail code brother" mean?

Comment: see below I've added some snippet

Comment: @Akshay I replied to your snippet but it is no longer there. I can manually check the status of the var_dump($_POST); and it is coming up with array(0) {}.

Comment: Is this your exact code?

Comment: Maybe trying adding `$body .= implode(',',$_POST)` to what the content of the post data is.