# PHP: Proper way to pass variables

Tags: php, mysql

I have this piece of PHP code installed on a server where i have also installed a DataBase. When i try to run it via URL `http://ptyxiaki2016.eu.pn/login.php?email=tade&password=1234` I got NULL to all the values.

> tade 1234 {"error":false,"uid":null,"user":{"name":null,"surname":null,"country":null,"email":null,"password":null,"telephone":null}}

My PHP code is below:

```
<?php
require_once 'DB_Functions.php';
require_once 'DB_Connect.php';
$db = new DB_Functions();

// json response array
$response = array("error" => FALSE);

if (isset($_GET['email']) && isset($_GET['password'])) {

// receiving the post params
$email = $_GET['email'];
$password = $_GET['password'];

// get the user by email and password
$user = $db->getUserByEmailAndPassword($email, $password);


if ($user != false) {
    // user is found
    $response["uid"] = $user["oid"];
    $response["error"] = FALSE;
    $response["uid"] = $user["oid"];
    $response["user"]["name"] = $user["name"];
    $response["user"]["surname"] = $user["surname"];
    $response["user"]["country"] = $user["country"];
    $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
    $response["user"]["password"] = $user["password"];
    $response["user"]["telephone"] = $user["telephone"];
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // user is not found with the credentials
    $response["error"] = TRUE;
    $response["error_msg"] = "Login credentials are wrong. Please try again!";
    echo json_encode($response);
}
} else {
// required post params is missing
$response["error"] = TRUE;
$response["error_msg"] = "Required parameters email or password is missing!";
echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

And this is the function `getUserByEmailAndPassword()` i call in the login. It is inside the DB_Functions.php I include.

```
public function getUserByEmailAndPassword($email, $password) {

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM owner WHERE email = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);

    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        $user = $stmt->bind_result($oid, $name, $surname, $country, $email, $password, $telephone);
        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
                printf("%s %s\n", $email, $password);
    }
        $stmt->close();
        return $user;
        }
    }
```

What am I missing here? My DB is OK, but, how can i retrieve the data?

Comment: Never ever **transmit passwords and login credentials on plain text over a GET request**. This is a serious security risk.

Comment: Over what request do i have to transmit?

Comment: Over POST, of course.

Comment: I get an error if i use POST, thats why i use GET

Comment: That is one of the worst excuse I have ever heard. You are basically letting people store their passwords in their browser history AND it's completely sniffable from network traffic. What's so difficult with replacing `$_GET` with `$_POST`, and using `<form method="post">`?

Comment: I am not experienced at all with php, I got this piece of code from somewere else. This is not an excuse, i am just trying to understand what i am doing wrong.

Comment: If i change the GET with POST i got an error message `Required parameters email or password is missing!`
How to use the `<form method="post">` ?
Can you at least help me with this rather than criticize? Thanks

Comment: @Kzaf I'd think that the reason for the critique is that working examples of code related to `GET` and `POST` can be found fairly easily on numerous websites. For instance, if I search `HTML PHP Post`, the second link itself is [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10057752/2298301). Because how Stack Overflow is designed, questions which might directly / indirectly imply a bit of insignificant prior research (on something that's fairly common), would unfortunately attract frowns. Don't be discouraged though, you essentially now know how to possibly avoid such situations in future questions :)

Comment: I don't even know that this is so big deal, i just change it to GET and it worked, so i left it like this. Can someone at least explain how to use POST in a proper way?

Comment: Have you really looked at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057752/html-form-post-to-php-page (also linked above) and it still doesn't clarify how to use `POST`?

Comment: @DhruvSaxena thank you, i got this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is here:

```
$user = $stmt->bind_result($oid, $name, $surname, $country, $email, $password, $telephone);
```

You bind result to variables ($oid, $name, ...), but return $user.

`bind_result` returns result of operation (true/false), but not result of query.

So result of call to getUserByEmailAndPassword() is bool value. If you'll run instead of `echo json_encode($response)` `echo json_encode($user)` you'll see it.

UPD: try this code instead of yours

```
if ($stmt->execute()) {
    $stmt->bind_result($user["oid"], $user["name"], ...)
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            printf("%s %s\n", $email, $password);
}
```

Comment: I see. Now i got a true. But the variables are still null, right? Sorry i am new to PHP and i dont get a lot of the functions

Comment: Try updated code. I cann't check, but it should works.