# How to parse a value from HTML form to a PHP value?

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

I want to update the order preparation time. I have this little HTML form, but I'cant pass it in a PHP variable right after this code. I've used Cookies, I've used POST method but none helped me about it.

```
<form>
            <input type="text" id="save_order_time" name="order_time<?php echo $order_id ?>" />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update Order Time" onclick="order_time_a();">
            </form>

<script>

            function order_time_a(){
                var input = $('.menu-order-detail').find('input[name="order_time<?php echo $order_id ?>"]').val();
                //var input = 25;
                    <?php 
                    //$order_time = '<script>var input = $(".menu-order-detail").find("input[name="order_time<?php echo $order_id "]").val();</script>';
                    //update_post_meta($order_id, 'foodbakery_order_time', $order_time); ?>

                console.log("Lets show something "+input);
                var d = new Date();
                d.setTime(d.getTime() + (1*24*60*60*1000));
                var expires = "expires="+ d.toGMTString();
                document.cookie = "order_time" + "=" + input + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
                console.log("Cookie was set. " + input);                    
            }

            </script>

            <?php

            echo ("<script>console.log('This code is executed first')</script>");
            //echo ('order_time'.$order_id);
            $order_time = $_COOKIE['order_time'];
            update_post_meta($order_id, 'foodbakery_order_time', $order_time);
```

When I use COOKIE solution the value that I've set in previous time is stored in the $order_time value. That's normal because I can't access COOKIE right after is set.

When I use POST method I get NULL in my database.

How can I implement the above?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things unclear in your explanation. Why are you using these different concepts next to each other?

- Form / POST
- Javascript
- COOKIE variable

I think you should try to only use the Form / POST option, see explanation here: [HTML Form POST to PHP page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057752/html-form-post-to-php-page)

---

Besides that, in your javascript part I see this: `var input = $('.menu-order-detail').find('input[name="order_time<?php echo $order_id ?>"]').val();`

You should create it like this to find the right object:
`var input = $('.menu-order-detail').find('input[name="order_time"]').val();`

Comment: thank you for your reply. I can find already the right value of my input object. I've put order_id because the php page code that I want to edit is for a list of orders, so I want the input value(order preparation time) for each order separetely. Moreover, I have all these concepts beacuse in a wordpress php file I want to add a form and handle its input value in order to update_post_meta of the order, as you can see in the last line of my code. Important think that all these must to be done in the same page, so I can't call another page using an action in post form